# How to default the Unity Lifetime Manager

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I'm updating a legacy codebase which was using Unity 3.5 for dependency injection. It's using a custom extension to set the default LifetimeManager, in much the same way as [this stackflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35199841/1207650).

However, now we've updated to the latest Unity 5.11, this no longer works.  Particularly:

```
Context.Policies.Set<ILifetimePolicy>(lifetimeManager, new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.TypeTo, e.Name));
```

as it seems the `Set()` method definitions have changed in the later version of Unity, and I can't work out exactly how they are supposed to be used.

How should this be done in the latest Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is no longer necessary to set the Context policies for the lifetime manager.  We can just set the manager on the `RegisterEventArgs`, along the lines of:

```
public class DefaultLifetimeManagerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly LifetimeManager _lifetimeManager;

    public DefaultLifetimeManagerExtension(LifetimeManager lifetimeManager)
    {
        _lifetimeManager = lifetimeManager;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // Set the default lifetime manager for registrations
        Context.Registering += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.LifetimeManager == null)
            {
                e.LifetimeManager = _lifetimeManager;
            }
        };
    }
}
```